# what does ":1" after a member variable mean?

Tags: c++

I came across this code while reading about Trees. Could anyone explain what the ": 1" after member variable "successor" mean?

```
template<class T>
class Node{  
 public:  
     Node() {  
         left = right = 0;  
     }  
     T key;  
     Node *left, *right;  
     unsigned int successor : 1;  
 };
```

I tried searching for this with various combination of " what does : after member variable mean in c++?" but did not find any answers.

Comment: Its a bitfield.

Comment: @Borgleader Thanks for the answer. I'll read more on bitfields.

Comment: @RevanayyaHiremath Not in this context.